# Why is this nested loop not working in Google Apps Script (Sheets/Admin) and throwing no errors?

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, nested-loops, google-admin-settings-api

I'm trying to find a streamlined way to keep members in about 100 Google groups up to date from info already in a Google Sheets workbook. One sheet has a list of 1700 students w/ columns for student email and group email. Another sheet contains a list of just the group names and the group emails. Based on the codes I found on it seems possible with Google apps script. Unfortunately, I have no previous experience with Apps Script and minimal experience with javascript. I've been trying to piece together a process that might look like this.

1. Deleting all current members of the groups.
2. Uploading the correct members.
3. Rinse and repeat.

Not the most elegant, but it seemed workable.

This is what I've done so far and I've hit a wall.

I found the combination of these 2 functions will remove all members from 1 group:

```
//Function to Remove 1 group member from 1 group
  function removeGroupMember(groupEmail, userEmail) {
  Logger.log(userEmail)
  userEmail = userEmail.trim();
  AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupEmail, userEmail);
}
//Remove all Members from 1 group
function removeAllMembers() {
  var groupEmail = 'groupemail@mydomain.org';
  var members = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupEmail).members;

  for (var m in members) {
    var member = members[m];
    var email = member.email;
    removeGroupMember(groupEmail, email)
  }
}
```

I thought I could nest another loop to pair it with this code that grabs the group emails from the sheet.

```
//get all of the groups from the spreadsheet
function getGroupsFromSpreadsheet(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('google_groups');
  const data = sheet.getRange(2,2,100).getValues();
  return data;
  logger.log(data)
}
```

This is what I came up with after a few trial and errors. It runs from the script editor and the execution log says it's successful, but then nothing actually happens in Google Admin - they're all still in the groups.

```
function removeAllMembers() {
  var groups =  [getGroupsFromSpreadsheet()];
  var groupEmail =  [getGroupsFromSpreadsheet()];
  var members = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupEmail).members;
  
  for (var element in groups) {
  
    for (var m in members) {
      var member = members[m];
      var email = member.email;
      removeGroupMember(groupEmail, email);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting `getGroupsFromSpreadsheet()` & `getGroupsFromSpreadsheet()` in brackets `[]`?

Comment: @Diego  - I read something (at some point) that made me think making the var an array would help get rid of an error that isn't happening anymore. It appears to run with or without the bracket. Again, no error message, but the members aren't removed from the groups.

Comment: I think you can figure this out by getting a better grasp of what is actually happening in your function. This is a really good opportunity for you to learn how to use the debugger. If [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints) don't help, try simply searching "how to use google apps script debugger". BTW the code doesn't throw errors because it finishes successfully, it's just not doing what you want it  to do.

Comment: Hello @Christine! Can you confirm the members haven't been removed? Please bear in mind that due to propagation, the changes might not show up immediately. Moreover, do you have the permissions needed in order to remove the members?

Comment: @Diego - The debugger would be really helpful if it worked. The script runs and when it hits a problematic line, the debugger just closes. Occasionally, I can see an error message flash too. But, if I run the same function without the debugger on, it runs without errors.

Comment: @ale13 - The members are removed only when I run the function removeAllMember with a single email plugged in. Otherwise, they don't come out even after 24 hours. As far as permissions, I have a super admin account and turned on the permissions for anything that said Admin, Groups, or sheets within the script UI (Resources>Advanced Google Services).

Answer (score 0):

Untested as I don't have a G Suite account. Have never worked with `AdminDirectory` API, so I don't know if below is the best way to do this.

---

```
function* getGroupEmailsFromSpreadsheet() {
  // Should allow caller to access each "group" with a 
  // simple for-of loop. Generator used here, but could
  // have used anything that would flatten the nested array
  // that Range.getValues() returns.
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.GetActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('google_groups');
  const data = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 100).getValues();
  
  for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < data.length; ++rowIndex) {
    for (let columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < data[0].length; ++columnIndex) {
      // Maybe do some validation here e.g. making sure email is a string, contains an "@" character
      yield data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }
  }
}


function* getAllMembersInGroup(groupKeyOrEmail) {
  // Should allow caller to access each "member" with a simple
  // for-of loop. Generator used here, so that call site
  // doesn't need to deal with handling pagination.
  
  const options = {
    maxResults: 200
  };
  
  // https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list#request
  let groupMembers = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupKeyOrEmail, options);
  do {
    for (const member of groupMembers.members) {
      yield member;
    }
    options.pageToken = groupMembers.nextPageToken;
    groupMembers = AdminDirectory.Members.list(groupKeyOrEmail, options)
  } while (groupMembers.nextPageToken);
}


function removeAllMembersFromAllGroups() {
  // Should remove all "members" in the "groups" on the sheet.
  for (const groupEmail of getGroupEmailsFromSpreadsheet()) {
    for (const member of getAllMembersInGroup(groupEmail)) {
      Logger.log(`Going to try and remove member ${member.email} from group ${groupEmail}.`);
      AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupEmail, member.email);
    }
  }
}
```

---

Before running the `removeAllMembersFromAllGroups` function:

1. It would be good if you randomly picked one group (`someGroup`) from your worksheet, randomly picked one member in that group (`someMember`) and then create/run a temporary function containing `AdminDirectory.Members.remove(someGroup, someMember)` -- except replace `someGroup` and `someMember` with the actual values you've chosen. Then check if that member has actually been removed from the group. This should prove whether the code can actually delete members from groups (or whether there is a problem even with this simple scenario).
2. Double-check that the script has all necessary permissions granted.
3. Then set up a breakpoint inside the `do-while` loop in `getAllMembersInGroup` as the `do-while` loop is untested. Then debug the `removeAllMembersFromAllGroups` function. You'll want to check that the `getAllMembersInGroup` generates a finite sequence of "members" (and doesn't loop forever).

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the code you have is in fact caused my the `groups` and `groupEmail` variables in the code. Therefore, I suggest you try this:

```
function getGroups() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET_ID').getSheetByName('SHEET_NAME');
   var groups = ss.getRange(2, 2, 2, 100).getValues();
   return groups;
}

function removeGroupMember(groupEmail, userEmail) {
   userEmail = userEmail.trim();
   AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupEmail, userEmail);
}

function removeAllMembers() {
   var groups = getGroups();
   for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
      var members = AdminDirectory.Members.list(theGroups[i][0]).members;
      for (var j = 0; j < members.length; j++) 
         removeGroupMember(theGroups[i][0], members[j].email);
   }
}
```

#### Reference

- [Range Class Apps Script - getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues);
- [SpreadsheetApp Class Apps Script - openById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) .